# Broadcast User Message to All Using Wall

Tags: linux, bash, shell

so I want to let the user enter a specific message either by pasting it or typing it themselves using wall and by using wall, broadcast it to all users. I the idea is that I don't want to have only one line of message but rather allow for as big of a message that they want without using a text file.

I came up with this:

```
...
elif [ $var -eq 3 ]

        echo "Enter your broadcast message (When done, wait 2 seconds):"
        broadcastThis= read -d '' -n 1 message

        while broadcastThis=`read -d '' -n 1 -t 2 c`
        do
            message+=$c
        done

        wall <<< $message
fi
```

I get an error stating the following:

> script: line 146: warning: here-document at line 141 delimited by
>   end-of-file (wanted `$message') script: line 147: syntax error:
>   unexpected end of file

I am really stuck at this point, it seems to have an issue on how wall is taking in the variable $message.

**EDIT:**
I made the changes that devnull suggested but now only the first letter of the user's input is being broadcasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<<` denotes a [here document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document).

What you're looking for is a herestring:

```
wall <<< "$message"
```

If you wanted a here document, you'd need to use the correct syntax:

```
wall << DELIMITER
"$message"
DELIMITER
```

Comment: Yea that got rid of the error but now its only broadcasting the first letter of the user's input and then the echo statement...

Comment: @bloodstorm17 Change the `while` loop to: `while read -d '' -n 1 -t 2 c` and remove `broadcastThis=` from the first `read` command too.